# Does "hosting a dinner" mean it is paid for?

Tags: british-english

Does "hosting a dinner" (in the UK) mean it is paid for, or just that it is being organised on behalf of the attendees?

Comment: One can host all manner of events, participation in which may or may not require payment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tricky. In general usage, hosting=paying-for. But it could also refer to an organised fund-raising event -- a political dinner, say -- where the host is providing only the venue, or even just their name, and in which guests were expected to pay an attendance fee that covered the cost of event and also provided contributions to whatever cause the host was supporting.

Comment: Pretty much the same in the US.